# Fabric / Crashlytics: How do I tell which types of devices are having OOMs?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I can see that the new beta of my (existing) app has a lot more OOMs than the current version does. I would like to learn more about the OOMs -- specifically which device(s) are experiencing them. For example: it would help a lot if it turns out that most OOMs are on iPad minis (in this case I would know how to fix the problem).

How can I get any more info about my OOMs other than how many occurred on a given day?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't encountered a way to find out more information directly in the Fabric console, but according to [Fabric documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/OOMs.html#how-should-you-go-about-debugging-ooms) you can debug by logging the parameters you are interested in at `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` and I see no reason why you couldn't just add device information there.

Comment: Thanks but there’s no link between OOMs and memory warnings that im aware of. Some devices throw memory warnings alllll the time

Comment: According to the same Fabric documentation OOM is a shorthand for Out of Memory, so I would expect there to be a connection. But I can see how it can be difficult to wade through the logs if you also get lots of memory warnings that don't result in OOM terminations.

Comment: Yeah that’s not how iOS works: warnings occur all the time and may lead to an OOM but there is no causal link